# Issue with HashMap ordering on generic type in Scala

Tags: java, scala

This is a simplified code to explain what happens. There are different type of Column classes one here is IntColumn. There are also ShortColumn, LongColumn etc.
GetMin does some processing on values from file and needs to return min value. Value type depends on Column type.

```
abstract class Column[A] {
    val name: String
    val size: Int
    def stringToValue(s: String): A
}

case class IntColumn(name: String) extends Column[Int] {
    val size = 4
    def stringToValue(s: String): Int = s.toInt
}

val col = IntColumn("id")

import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

def getMin[A](col: Column[A]): (A, Int) = {
    val hm = HashMap[A, Int]()

    // process some data from csv file...

    hm.put(col.stringToValue("1"), 1)
    hm.put(col.stringToValue("2"), 1)
    hm.put(col.stringToValue("3"), 1)

    hm.min // get min HashMap item
}

val min = getMin(col) // expecting (1, 1) of type (Int, Int)
```

When executing getMin I get the error below.
I thought compiler here has enough information to figure out what A is and be able to compare values in a HashMap.

```
Error:(21, 9) No implicit Ordering defined for (A, Int).
    hm.min
       ^
Error:(21, 9) not enough arguments for method min: (implicit cmp: Ordering[(A, Int)])(A, Int).
Unspecified value parameter cmp.
    hm.min
       ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point of `hm.min` call the compiler only has knowledge that the key of the hash map is some abstract type `A`. It doesn't automatically keep track of any implicits associated with abstract types.

There are basically two ways to solve this:

1. Either change the definition of `getMin` to take this implicit `Ordering`:

   ```
   def getMin[A: Ordering](col: Column[A]): (A, Int)
   ```

   At the point of `getMin` call the compiler knows that the argument has a concrete type `Column[Int]`. It will be able to figure out the implicit `Ordering` and pass it to `getMin`.
2. Or make the `Column` hold the `Ordering` for its content type:

   ```
   abstract class Column[A](implicit val ord: Ordering[A])
   ```

   The `Ordering` will be provided and stored from column creation `val col = IntColumn("id")`

   You would also have to make this `Ordering` available for `hm.min` by importing it in `getMin`:

   ```
   def getMin[A](col: Column[A]): (A, Int) = {
     import col.ord
     // ... everything else stays the same
   ```

Comment: This worked great! Although could you please explain what actually happens here [A: Ordering]? I didn't see this notation before.

Comment: It's called context bound. You can google for some articles on this term. Basically, it's just a shorthand for having an implicit parameter. For example `def f[T : Ordering](arg: T)` is generally equivalent to `def f[T](arg: T)(implicit ev: Ordering[T])`.